# Minimize $\operatorname{tr} \left(X^T L X \right)$ subject to inequality constraints

Tags: optimization, trace

Given a matrix $Y$, a **symmetric** matrix $L$ and a **binary** matrix $B$, I would like to solve an optimization problem of the form

$$ \min_{X} \quad \operatorname{trace} \left( X^T L X \right) \quad\quad \text{s.t.} \quad  \|B\circ X-Y\|_{\text{F}} \leq \epsilon $$

where $\circ$ denotes the [Hadamard product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)) (a.k.a., element-wise product) and the norm is the Frobenius norm. How to solve this optimization problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It is a convex optimization problem, so you can plug into any CVX solver. Or would you rather ask to compute an algorithm to solve it?

Comment: @VanBaffo Thank you for your answer，Can you tell me how to solve this optimization problem with CVX solver.

Comment: You can use CVX in MATLAB or in python for instance http://cvxr.com/cvx/

Comment: Binary is $0,1$ or $\pm 1$?

Comment: You could be considerate and pick names for the dimensions of the matrices.

Comment: If you squared the Frobenius norm, you would have a QCQP.

Comment: Is $L$ positive definite?